# Change text color depending on Dark or light mode "Native ads"

Tags: xml, flutter, kotlin, admob

I'm using native ads in my flutter app the ad layout designed by android native `XML File`
and I have a dark and light theme in my flutter app
**I want to change native ads text colour** when the user change to dark/light mode.

the native ad text colours are set in android native code, not in dart files.

kotlin code :

```
package com.codelab.flutter.admobinlineads;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Map;

import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin;

class ListTileNativeAdFactory implements GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory {

    private final Context context;

    ListTileNativeAdFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public NativeAdView createNativeAd(
            NativeAd nativeAd, Map<String, Object> customOptions) {
        NativeAdView nativeAdView = (NativeAdView) LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_tile_native_ad, null);

        TextView attributionViewSmall = nativeAdView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_small);
        TextView attributionViewLarge = nativeAdView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_large);

        ImageView iconView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_tile_native_ad_icon);
        NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();
        if (icon != null) {
            attributionViewSmall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            attributionViewLarge.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iconView.setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
        } else {
            attributionViewSmall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            attributionViewLarge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        nativeAdView.setIconView(iconView);

        TextView headlineView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_headline);
        headlineView.setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
        nativeAdView.setHeadlineView(headlineView);

        TextView bodyView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_body);
        bodyView.setText(nativeAd.getBody());
        bodyView.setVisibility(nativeAd.getBody() != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        nativeAdView.setBodyView(bodyView);

        nativeAdView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

        return nativeAdView;
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ad layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F19938"
            android:text="Ad"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_list_tile_native_ad_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:background="#EDEDED" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_large"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="#F19938"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ad"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_tile_native_ad_headline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_tile_native_ad_body"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#828282"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:text="body" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

[image: native ads]

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm having the same question...

Comment: did you get the answer?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The key is using `customOptions` for the native Ad.

So in Flutter, you would initialize `NativeAd` as follows:

```
NativeAd nativeAd = NativeAd(
  adUnitId: adUnitId,
  factoryId: factoryId,
  request: AdRequest(),
  listener: NativeAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
      if(onAdLoaded != null) { onAdLoaded(); }
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      ad.dispose();
    },
  ),
  customOptions: {
    ‘darkMode’: isDarkMode,
  }
);
```

Then in Java, you can just use something like this (after initializing `headlineView`):

```
Boolean darkMode = (Boolean) customOptions.get(“darkMode”);
if (darkMode == null) { darkMode = false; }
headlineView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(darkMode ? “#FFFFFF” : “#000000”));
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question or if you need any more information!!

Comment: customOptions not calling on change theme model. please let me know how to call that option every time on change theme.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing that right now would be to refresh the ad or something like that, if that works for you (it depends on the specific UI and UX you currently have).

Comment: Your solution is working on the next launch. I want to change the text color on changing the theme(Dark/Light).

Comment: All you need to do is make sure the ad gets refreshed whenever the theme changes. If you control the theme (dark/light) on a page without an ad, then that should be pretty straightforward (since you can just refresh the ad when you come back to the page). Does that make sense?

Comment: Brilliant! Spend the last 2 days looking for solutions and this solved it!

Answer (score -1):

Create two files one for light theme \color.xml, another one for  dark theme \color.xml(night)

colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <resources>
           <color name="text_primary">#FFFFFF</color>
      </resources>
```

colors.xml(night)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <resources>
           <color name="text_primary">#333333</color>
      </resources>
```

In layout

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
        />
```

it will change textcolor automatically.